# JavaScript I want to navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to know what to do exactly.
I'm editing a template and I want to add some items in the nav-bar to redirect me to an outer page.
it works fine the full size page but in mobile size it don't it only move me in the same page.
this is the function that responsible for the operation:

```js
var OnePageNavigation = function() {
    var navToggler = $('.site-menu-toggle');
    $("body").on("click", ".main-menu li a[href^='#'], .smoothscroll[href^='#'], .site-mobile-menu .site-nav-wrap li a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $(hash).offset().top
      }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo', function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });

    });
  };
```

and this is the template: https://technext.github.io/banker/index.html
this is the source: https://github.com/technext/banker

what can I add to the function or the code to allow me to navigate to outer pages?

Sorry if my explanation was bad my English is not the best

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set the `body`'s `scroll-behaviour` to `smooth` in CSS. Then set the `href` of the navbar links to `#section_name`.

There is a w3schools documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1). Fare thee well.